# How to use np.prod to rewrite python for loop function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am using pandas and numpy to deal with data, and I have a python function:

```
mt= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

def getnpx(mt, age, interest):
    val = 1
    initval = 1
    for i in range(age, 6):
        val = val * mt[i]
        intval = val / (1 + interest) ** (i + 1 - age)
        initval = initval + intval
    return initval
```

If directly use pd.apply(getnpx),it will be very slow since the data size is very large ,so I want to convert this function into numpy,I think I maybe can use np.prod to rewrite it,but have no idea how to continue,since this function is very complicated!

Any friend can help?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect from your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `np.prod`, you want `np.cumprod`:

```
def getnpx_(mt, age, interest):
    return 1 + (np.cumprod(mt[age:6]) / (1+interest)**np.arange(1,(7-age))).sum()

age, interest = 3, 0.5
print(np.isclose(getnpx(mt, age, interest), getnpx_(mt, age, interest) ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.I have updated my question can you also help me rewrite another function:

Comment: Hi friend,I opend another related question ,if you would please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455930/numpy-how-to-use-np-cumprod-to-rewrite-python-for-i-in-range-function

Comment: Hi friend thank you very much for your answer,can you also help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457867/numpy-how-to-use-np-cumprod-to-vectorize-python-for-i-in-range-function?noredirect=1#comment122770265_69457867