# Numpy how to use np.cumprod to rewrite python for i in range function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have two python functions. The first one:

```
mt = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
age, interest = 3, 0.5

def getnpx(mt, age, interest):
    val = 1
    initval = 1
    for i in range(age, 6):
        val = val * mt[i]
        intval = val / (1 + interest) ** (i + 1 - age)
        initval = initval + intval
    return initval
```

The output is:

```
48.111111111111114
```

In order to make it faster, I used numpy to vectorize it:

```
def getnpx_(mt, age, interest):
    print(np.cumprod(mt[age:6]) / (1 + interest)**np.arange(1, 7 - age))
    return 1 + (np.cumprod(mt[age:6]) / (1 + interest)**np.arange(1, 7 - age)).sum()

getnpx_(mt, age, interest)
```

It works and the output is still:

```
48.111111111111114
```

However I have no idea how to rewrite my second function by numpy:

```
pt1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
pt2 = np.array([2, 4, 3, 4, 7, 4, 8])
pvaltable = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

def jointpval(pt1, pt2, age1, age2):
    j = age1
    for i in range(age2, 6):
        k = min(j, 135)
        pvaltable[i] = pt1[k] * pt2[i]
        j = j + 1
    return pvaltable

jointpval(pt1, pt2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0, 28, 20,  0])
```

I expect to be able to convert the loop

```
for i in range(age2, 6):
```

To something like:

```
np.cumprod(pt1[age:6])
```

The final output should be the same as:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0, 28, 20,  0])
```

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output? How is `pandas` involved here?

Comment: Hi @rpanai thank you for your reply I have updated my question please check!

Comment: Does 135 need to be hardcoded?

Comment: yes,but 135 can be smaller as 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution:

```py
import numpy as np
pt1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
pt2 = np.array([2, 4, 3, 4, 7, 4, 8])

def jointpval(pt1, pt2, age1, age2):
    pvaltable = np.zeros(len(pt1))
    idx2 = np.arange(age2, 6)
    idx1 = np.arange(len(idx2)) + age1
    idx1 = np.where(idx1 > 135, 135, idx1) 
    pvaltable[idx2] = pt1[idx1] * pt2[idx2]
    return pvaltable
```

Where `jointpval(pt1, pt2, 3, 4)` returns

```sh
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 28., 20.,  0.])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. First link doesn't work.

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484626/numpy-operands-shape-error-after-vectorizing-function-cumprod-and-sum-invol

Comment: Hi friend thank you for your advice ,can you help this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485803/numpy-vertical-function-float-object-is-not-subscriptable  I have made it very simple.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not hard coding your array sizes. For example:

```
def getnpx_(mt, age, interest):
    return 1 + (np.cumprod(mt[age:-1]) / (1 + interest)**np.arange(1, len(mt) - age)).sum()
```

Notice that the index `age:-1` agnostic to the size of `mt`, and `mt.size - age` saves you the trouble of recoding the function every time you have a different `mt`.

Your solution for the second case is pretty much on-point. I might recommend using `np.clip` rather than where to also set the lower bound to zero:

```
def jointpval(pt1, pt2, age1, age2):
    pvaltable = np.zeros(len(pt1))
    idx = np.arange(len(pt2) - age2 - 1)
    idx1 = np.clip(idx + age1, 0, len(pt1) - 1)
    idx2 = idx + age2
    pvaltable[idx2] = pt1[idx1] * pt2[idx2]
    return pvaltable
```

You could also use `np.minimum` to implement vectorized `min` directly:

```
idx1 = np.minimum(idx + age1, len(pt1) - 1)
```

Keep in mind that ranges are exclusive on the upper bound. Both of your functions are truncating the computation of the last element for this reason. It is likely that `idx = np.arange(len(pt2) - age2 - 1)` should really be `idx = np.arange(len(pt2) - age2)` in `jointpval`, while `mt[age:-1]` should be `mt[age:]`, and `np.arange(1, len(mt) - age)` should be `np.arange(len(mt) - age)` in `genpx_`.

Comment: Hi friend thank you very much for your answer,can you also help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457867/numpy-how-to-use-np-cumprod-to-vectorize-python-for-i-in-range-function?noredirect=1#comment122770265_69457867

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484626/numpy-operands-shape-error-after-vectorizing-function-cumprod-and-sum-invol