# Numpy how to use np.cumprod to vectorize python for i in range function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have two python functions. The first one:

```
import numpy as np
import math
mt = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
age, interest = 3, 0.5

def getnpx(mt, age, interest):
    val = 1
    initval = 1
    for i in range(age, 7):
        val = val * mt[i]
        intval = val / (1 + interest) ** (i + 1 - age)
        initval = initval + intval
    return initval
```

The output is:

```
214.03703703703704
```

In order to make it faster, I used numpy to vectorize it:

```
def getnpx_(mt, age, interest):
    return 1 + (np.cumprod(mt[age:7]) / (1 + interest)**np.arange(1, 8 - age)).sum()

getnpx_(mt, age, interest)
```

It works and the output is still:

```
214.03703703703704
```

However I have no idea how to vectorize my another function by numpy:

```py
def getnpx2(mt, age, interest):
    val = mt[age]
    initval = 1
    for i in range(age + 2, 8):
        val *= mt[i - 1]
        intval = val / (1 + interest) ** (i - age - 1) / mt[age]
        initval = initval + intval
    return initval
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455930/numpy-how-to-use-np-cumprod-to-rewrite-python-for-i-in-range-function

Comment: Thank you for your reply,first the /mt[age] is different,second,if math.isnan(intval):
          intval = 0
          initval = initval + intval is different

Comment: you can use numpy.vectorize but it doesn't give  you any speed gain. The best way is use numpy functions like you did in getnpx_ function. You can also try using numba https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/vectorize.html#the-vectorize-decorator

Comment: Your code wasn't well formatted so i edited. Please check the last function as future reference.

Comment: Yes friend@rpanai ,thank you so much,very nice to see you again!

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are doing after `if math.isnan(intval)`. Do you mind to share the reference from where are you taking these formulas?

Comment: @rpanai sorry for that I just deleted that line,because it is not important in my code and I can use np.where replace the nan value to 0.Thanks again!

Comment: Can you provide the reference for the formula defined in `intval` I'm kind of confused about brackets.

Comment: Sorry my friend,I realy have no idea what do you mean by the formula defined in tval...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is:

```
def getnpx_(mt, age, interest):
    return (np.cumprod(mt[age:7]) / (1 + interest)**np.arange(7 - age)).sum() / mt[age]
```

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484626/numpy-operands-shape-error-after-vectorizing-function-cumprod-and-sum-invol