# Numpy how to vectorize python function use np.cumprod

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I have a python function:

```
pval = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0.999709, 0.99973,0.999743,0.999706, 0.999675, 0.99965,  0.999629])
age1=4
age2=8

def getnpxtocert(mt, age, age2):
    val = mt[age]
    for i in range(age + 1,age2):
        val = val * mt[i]
    return val

getnpxtocertv(pval,age1,age2)
```

The output is:

```
0.9991822227268075
```

And then I tried to use cumprod to vectorize it:

```
def getnpxtocertv(mt, age, age2):
    return (mt[age]*np.cumprod(mt[age+1:age2])).sum()

getnpxtocert(pval,age1,age2)
```

But the output is:

```
2.998330301296807
```

What did I wrong?Any friend can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `cumprod` and `sum`.  Just use `prod`:

```
def getnpxtocert_v2(mt, age, age2):
    return np.prod(mt[age:age2])
```

Comparison:

```
In [23]: getnpxtocert(pval, age1, age2)
Out[23]: 0.9991822227268075

In [24]: getnpxtocert_v2(pval, age1, age2)
Out[24]: 0.9991822227268075
```

`cumprod` takes an array `[x0, x1, x2, ...]` and returns an array with the same length containing `[x0, x0*x1, x0*x1*x2, ...]`.  `prod` returns the scalar that is the product of all the elements `x0*x1*x2*...`.

Comment: Thank you for your right answer,it works,can you also help this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457867/numpy-how-to-use-np-cumprod-to-vectorize-python-for-i-in-range-function?noredirect=1#comment122769618_69457867

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484626/numpy-operands-shape-error-after-vectorizing-function-cumprod-and-sum-invol